# how to download excel file for client machine?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

1.Input type button show to client-side and click on this button, call the javascript method.

```
            <input type="button" id="btnImportExcel" name="btnImportExcel" value="Export to Excel" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Export_Excel();" style="width: 10%" />
```

2. This javascript method retrieves the following parameters value and passes to the code behind web method.

   ```
       function Export_Excel() {
                   debugger;
                   var Showdata = {};
                   Showdata.startdate = $("[id*=txtbegindate]").val();
                   Showdata.enddate = $("[id*=txtenddate]").val();
                   if ($('input[id*=RadioButton1]').is(":checked")) {
                       Showdata.radio = 1;
                   }
                   else if ($('input[id*=RadioButton2]').is(":checked")) {
                       Showdata.radio = 2;
                   }
                   $('#divProgress').show();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "Agent_HomePage.aspx/efgh",
                       data: '{xyz: ' + JSON.stringify(Showdata) + '}',
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (response) {
                           alert(response.d);
                       },
                       error: function (response) {
                           alert("Error");
                       }
                   });
                   $('#divProgress').hide();
                   $('div#OuterShowImageEdu').on('dialogclose', function (event) {
                       alert('closed');
                   });
               }
   ```
3. we create a web method and using the class object retrieve all parameters values and call the WCF service and pass parameters value.

   ```
       [WebMethod]
           [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
           public static string efgh(Showdata xyz)
           {
               string result = "";
               DataTable dt;
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               string filename = string.Empty;
               try
               {
                   string Sdate = string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", xyz.startdate);
                   string Edate = string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", xyz.enddate);
                   List<object> listfinal = new List<object>();
                   HelloServiceClient client = new HelloServiceClient();
                   string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
                   var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
                   if (xyz.radio == "1")
                   {
                       dt = client.OracleConert_Excel(Convert.ToDateTime(Sdate), Convert.ToDateTime(Edate), dec_cod, 1);
                       filename = path + "\\Carrier_House_Manifest" + "_" + date + ".xls";
                       ExporttoExcel(dt, filename);
                   }
                   else { }
               }        
               catch (Exception ex)
               { result = ex.Message; }
               return result;
           }
   ```
4. After WCF services execute successfully and return the result then result convert to excel file.

   ```
       private static void ExporttoExcel(DataTable dt, string fileName)
           {
               int i = 0;
               int j = 0;
               string data = null;

               Excel.Application xlApp;
               Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
               Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

               object misValue = Missing.Value;
               xlApp = new Excel.Application();
               xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
               xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

               for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dt.Columns.Count; i1++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1] = dt.Columns[i1].ColumnName;
                   xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "AA1").Font.Bold = true;
                   xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "AA1").ColumnWidth = "22";
                   xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "AA1").Borders.Weight = 4d;
                   //xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "AA1").Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightSteelBlue;
               }
               for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
               {
                   int s = i + 1;
                   for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                   {
                       data = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                       xlWorkSheet.Cells[s + 1, j + 1] = data;
                   }
               }
               xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
               xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
               xlApp.Quit();
               releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
               releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
               releaseObject(xlApp);
           }
   ```

   Issue :
   I am getting problem file download a client machine.I am trying to file download in client machine but file download on the server.Also, the same code is proper working in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SheetJS js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

Use `generateAndDownloadXLSX` to download excel file in your page.

Comment: can you give me the solution in asp.net in code project because I don't want to use any extra JS file in my solution?